# Objects not stacking via z-index with flexbox and draggable

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have been having some difficulty getting some z-indexing to work properly.  What I've seen is that when I drag an image from the center and try to drop it into a box on the outside area, the dragging image is placed beneath every other object.  Once I drag it into a box and try to drag it out, it might drag into other areas okay or it might not.  That leads me to believe that the z-index of the img itself does not matter at all but rather the parent it's from.  I have a scrollbar in there which seem to have some affect on the z index but the issue still persists with or without it, just in a different way.

I am setting the z index of the img to 10000 on the start of the drag (which I'm seeing properly) and setting it back to 3 at the stop (which I'm also seeing properly).  Those values aren't doing anything for actually fixing the problem.

```
function makeDraggable() {
    $(".portrait").draggable({
        scroll: false,
        revert: 'invalid',
        stack: false,
        cursor: "pointer",

        start: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css("z-index", 10000);
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).css("z-index", 3);
        }
    });
};
```

There's quite a bit of code to post here so I have created a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nyj9unka/4/

EDIT:  While I haven't been able to get this to work, I've been thinking about getting this to work with another type tool.  Would another framework be better to use to achieve the same type of layout?  I'm imagining my issues here are coming down to my lack of js knowledge, particularly with flexbox.

EDIT2: Bumping due to low responses

EDIT3: Last bump before I stop trying and scrap this method

Comment: Set `overflow:visible` on `#main > championList`

Comment: That didn't seem to work.  I need the `overflow-y: scroll;` to create the scrollbar.  Even without the scrollbar, if I drag an img to the left side and drag it off, it will appear as underneath the main `championList` area.